# How to go-to function definition with .R file in VSCode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've recently had to get back into R for some esoteric statistical packages, and I've been running into some challenges trying to understand the packages. My usual go-to with python would be to cmd click my way deeper and deeper through definitions until arriving to the base modules, however I'm not able to do that with R files.

I've installed the R extension and attached my R environment, and it's clear that's working since I'm getting to the tooltips for help, just not able to open the base files (which I can do in R Studio).

See (horribly formatted) images below

[image: Causal impact highlighting]

[image]

Comment: I assume you've already loaded the package with `library()`? The definition for that function works for me. I also have in my vscode settings json `"r.rpath.mac": "/usr/local/bin/R"` which points to my vanilla R (not radian), and I think this may be needed for help functions and definitions. Also need to have the R `languageserver` package installed

Comment: Thanks! Yes to all of those questions, regarding library() loading I'm doing so in an R Interactive terminal session, maybe there's a different way I should be loading?

Comment: Ah. I think this is intended behavior. In your script (.R, .rmd, .qmd, etc.), if you do not have a `library()` or `require()` statement for the `CausalImpact` earlier in your script, the language server does not know where the `CausalImpact()` function is coming from. Do you get the definition if you explicity show the namespace in the function call? (E.g., `CausalImpact::CausalImpact()`)

Comment: I think it works like this because best practice would be to have the script be self-sufficient in documenting which namespaces are loaded to the search list with `library()` or `require()`. If this does not work, I would check the output of `which R` and `which radian` in your bash or zsh terminal and make sure this matches in your vscode settings the values for `"r.rpath.mac"` and `"r.rterm.mac"` respectively

Comment: Brilliant! You're correct that the issue was that I was using the implied `CausalImpact` namespace when seeking function definition. Unfortunately looks like I can't dive much deeper due to R's love of unspecified library associations (i.e. can't dive deeper on where "RunWithBstsModel()" is defined), guessing an Intellisense limitation without an active kernel. 

If you'd like to post as an answer I'd be happy to mark yours as correct, otherwise will go ahead and answer my own question here.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can only use that definition lsp hotkey for a package's exported functions. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to look at internal functions.

Comment: I generally bind the vscode palette command "R Help Panel: Open help for selection" to a hotkey to get documentation for package functions (using R's `help() command`). The documentation is generally pretty good for many packages and I find myself using it much more than F12 to look at the definitions. Also no worries making an answer happy to help 

Comment: Ah. I learned something new. You can use triple colon to access some internal functions, e.g. try typing `CausalImpact:::RunWithBstsModel` in the R console